# Getting the two values from Python

Tags: python

Hi guys I am printing a bunch of these coordinates in a while loop. It looks like this:

```
{u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [-83.118532, 42.378364]}
{u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [-86.637723, 36.04577]}
{u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [-77.040753, 38.998019]}
{u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [-105.205712, 39.665206]}
{u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [-86.303772, 39.9525]}
{u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [-38.386702, -12.950518]}
...
```

My first question would be, if I want to grab the 2 values and say add them to a double. Like

```
Double latitude = -83.118532
Double longitude = 42.378364
```

And then  make it to where `latitude = -86.637723` and `longitude = 36.04577`... et cetera

What would be the best way to do that? I am using Tweepy to output a user's coordinates if that helps at all.

Basically I am trying to grab the longitude value and latitude value because I am eventually going to plot those on a map.

Hopefully my question is clear! If you have any questions let me know!

Comment: Please show the code you are using to print, and we can show you how to modify it for your purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to get the lat and long cordinates from that data structure is to use unpacking. Something like this:

```
yourDict = {u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [-38.386702, -12.950518]}
latitude, longitude  = yourDict['coordinates']

print latitude
#=> -38.386702

print longitude 
#=> -12.950518
```

Using unpacking in this way, you can easily use the data structure you've created in the most semantic way.

Comment: if the 2 values in the u'coordinates' are constantly changing though wouldnt this not work?

Comment: no its effectively a reference to that value in the array, because its a shallow copy. So when the array value changes; the referenced long lat corrodinate will change. @JakeSmith

Comment: I'm outputting -38.386702, and -12.9505 constantly though. Am I doing this wrong? I'll update my code with what I put in yours.

Comment: @agconti float values are immutable. They will *not* change when the list changes.

Comment: @JakeSmith: he was defining yourDict as an example so he had something  to reference. You weren't supposed to put it in the code. In your case, "yourDict" is `status.coordinates`.

Comment: @JakeSmith, you're right. the values wont change unless you reference the list directly, which would ruin the purpose of your data structure.

Answer (score 2):

What you're printing is a native Python data structure: a dictionary containing a string and a list. To reference the coordinate values, you could do this:

```
data = {u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [-83.118532, 42.378364]}
latitude, longitude = data['coordinates']
```

I recommend you [read up](http://books.google.com/books?id=E5qi1BXgvFwC&pg=PA68&lpg=PA68&dq=python+native+data+structures&source=bl&ots=id_HhQhs0x&sig=DMNFQPX578XGTwzFI4kIENMY8hw&hl=en&sa=X&ei=gLvqU6XMK5a3yATm1YDYCQ&ved=0CFwQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=python%20native%20data%20structures&f=false) on Python's native data structures.

Comment: Looks like I started writing mine before I saw yours.

Answer (score 1):

There's no while loop in your code. What value are you printing, and where?

Let's say you're printing something called `coords`

`coords  = {u'type': u'Point', u'coordinates': [-38.386702, -12.950518]}`

That's a [dict](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/dictionary/python-dictionary-quick-guide) type, and the string `coordinates` is a key. With a dict type you can access the information of the key by going like this:

```
latitude = coords['coordinates'][0]
longitude = coords['coordinates'][1]
```